# Searching my own answers

Tags: support, answers, search

Is there a way to search answers written by me for specific word/words?  I am looking at these because sometimes I look at a question and realize answering similar before and trying to locate that answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your profile page, then use the search button from there.  Don't remove the `user:48093` from the search box.

You can also use `user:me`. See [How do I search?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/searching) in the Help Centre for more options.